# Is there a way to easily share Workspace settings (folder mappings) for Visual Studio Online / Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I want to move from having a single Visual Studio (Online) workspace for all my Projects to having a separate Workspace for each Project (because: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/30/using-multiple-workspaces-with-visual-studio.aspx).

This all works out fine, but now I want to roll out this new approach to my colleagues and have come across the problem that it looks like there is no easy way to share Workspace settings with them.

Here is the official advice from an MSDN article for VS 2013 titled "Create and work with workspaces":

> Q: Can I reuse and share folder mappings?
>
> A: Yes. If you want to reuse or share folder mappings with other team
>   members, you can copy the folder mappings. Simply open the shortcut
>   menu in the Working folders list and choose Copy. To reuse the folder
>   mappings, paste them into another version control workspace or a build
>   definition workspace. To share the folder mappings with your
>   teammates, paste them into a text file and then share the file.
>
> source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx#copy_paste

I think the answer should have been *"No. There is no way exporting and importing Workspace folder mappings"*. The suggestion to "paste them into a text file and share the file" is simply hilarious.

My research has turned up that for the server version of Team Foundation Server there is a thing called workspace templates:

> With workspace templates you can provide your developers with a
>   standard way of organizing their workspace. Your whole team uses the
>   same structure and enjoys all the benefits.
>
> http://roadtoalm.com/2011/10/25/hidden-gems-in-tfspart-6-managing-workspaces-in-tfs-with-workspace-templates/

As far is I know this is not available in Visual Studio Online (the cloud version of Team Foundation Server).

**So my question is:
Is there a way to easily share Workspace settings (folder mappings) for Visual Studio Online / Team Foundation Server?
If not, does anybody know of a better way than the copy / paste / share suggestion?**

Comment: I have also looked around for config files in the C:\Users\Frank van Eykelen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation folder.

Comment: Workspace Templates shouldn't be tied to on-premises TFS servers.  Did you install the Power Tools?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I did install the Power Tools, but could not get it to work like explained in the "Hidden Gems in TFS–Part 6 Managing workspaces in TFS with Workspace templates" article. I checked again and found it here: Click Team Members > Team Utilities > Workspace templates. Quite obvious after all.... I'll answer my own question once I have experimented with what I've found there. I have added a template, used it to create a new workspace. I will now investigate the sharing part of these templates. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the followup Frank, sorry we hid this functionality in a power tool and not in the main product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: yes, there is an easy way.

Install "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools": https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

After installing you will have a new option in Team Explorer: Team Members. Click it.

[image: After installing you will have a new option in Team Explorer: Team Members]

Click "Team Utilities".

[image]

Click "Add Template".

[image]

Select the Workspace you want to create a template for and click "Create".

[image]

Review the settings of the template and click "Create".

[image]

Your new template will be appear under "Workspace Templates" for all other team members after they have installed the Power Tools. When they click the template a Create Workspace dialog will open, based on the settings in the template.

[image]

Thanks to @EdwardThomson for pointing me in the right direction.