# Are workspace templates as implemented in Powertools for TFS 2013 still available in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

In respect to the following question [Is there a way to easily share Workspace settings (folder mappings) for Visual Studio Online / Team Foundation Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062962/is-there-a-way-to-easily-share-workspace-settings-folder-mappings-for-visual-s) and an entry I found regarding to this topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9b16b30-4534-4781-a2e8-fb413a2df0af/power-tools-for-tfs-2017-with-vs-2017-rc?forum=tfsgeneral I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to achieve this very much needed functionality in TFS 2017?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot create the workspace templates with VS 2017 for now.

According to [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#a-idknownissues-aknown-issues) it says most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017 that means no separate power tools for TFS 2017.

But the **Team Utilities** feature component is not integrated, that means these haven't shipped for Visual Studio 2017.

I have submitted a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/30925201-support-creating-workspace-templates-in-visual-stu) for you to suggest this feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

Another similar thread for your reference: [Team Members Team Utilities section in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812707/team-members-team-utilities-section-in-vs-2017)

Comment: @Andi thank you very muchh for reading and answering => accepted answer. but this breaks a lot ... i still hope to read how others managed to solve this issue.